# Using .not with dynamically added classes in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm using addClass() to add .expanded to an element on click. I then don't want another block of code to match that element anymore. I'm using a combination of .not() and .on() to try and get jQuery to notice the newly added class, but not having much luck - the handler I've written goes something like this:

```
    $(".person").not("expanded").on({
            mouseleave:...
    });
```

Though obviously my .on() syntax isn't correct above, how can I utilise .not() with newly added classnames?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want live event, you can try something like this:

```
$(document).on('mouseleave','.person:not(.expanded)',function(){
  ...
})
```

The selector `'.person:not(.expanded)'` will be used to filter the event.

If you used `$('.person:not(.expanded)').on('mouseleave',function() { ...}`, it will attached the event handler only to the selected elements at this moment. If you changed `expanded` class of an element, it will not be updated.

Better than `document` you should attach the delegate to the container of your person elements (for performance reason). See [`on` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: +1. Just note that it's VERY unefficeint to attach a delegate event to the document. You should attach to the closest element that contains the dyanmic `.person`

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to attach a mouseover to the same statement, but firing a different function? OR would I have to write another similar handler?

Comment: Yes, but for live event, you have to attach the delegate to a container (maybe not the document...)

Comment: Yes, see the on() syntax. You can do `on({mouseleave:x , mouseon:y},'.person:not(.expanded)')`

Comment: Ah yes, I see. But How can I pass the '.person' object to the mouseleave/over functions, rather than the the delegate object?

Comment: `this` will refers to the .person

Answer (score 0):

You missed the `.` on the `not()` selector:

```
$(".person").not(".expanded").on('mouseleave', function() {
    // code...
});
```

Comment: That was a typo in my questions, the problem still stand even with proper syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Well, technically jQuery will not *notice* when an element is added or a class name is removed.

Event delegation works this way: you bind the event handlers to a parent (up to the document if needed). `.on()` will use the selector parameter to execute the event handlers selectively to the "selector" parameter (if provided).

```
$("#someparent").on('mouseleave', '.person:not(.expanded)', function() {
    ...
});
```

The event "mouseleave" will bubble up to the element `#someparent` and the target of the event (basically the element from which the event was triggered will be checked upon the provided selector `.person:not(.expanded)`. If it matches, the event handler is executed.

Note that you can delegate to the document but it is better to delegation as close as possible to event targets.

Answer (score 0):

You can also remove the event handler from the desired element:

`$("#removeHandlerFromMe").unbind('mouseleave')`